# I am trying to adopt a flowchart design that i found online and I got stucked. How do i get the desired design in the codepen attached below?

Tags: html, css

[Codepen design of the flowchart i am trying to design](https://codepen.io/Lekwuwa/pen/LYgaEJZ)

Here is the code snippet of the flowchart i am adapting. I took it from a codepen example i saw online and i have been trying to redesign it. Just don't know how to use div tags with headers instaed of span tags.

```css
 #tree {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}

#tree * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#tree .branch {
  padding: 5px 0 5px 20px;
}

#tree .branch:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 170px;
}

#tree .branch:not(:first-child):after {
  content: "";
  width: 20px;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  left: 150px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: 1px;
}

.entry {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 42px;
  display: block;
}

.entry:before {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px;
}

.entry:first-child:after {
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 0;
}

.entry:first-child:before {
  width: 10px;
  height: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: 1px;
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 0;
}
.entry span.hide{
    display: none;
}

.entry:after {
  content: "";
  width: 20px;
  transition: border 0.5s;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: 1px;
}
.entry-sole:after {
  content: "";
  width: 20px;
  transition: border 0.5s;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: 1px;
}

.entry:last-child:before {
  width: 10px;
  height: 50%;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;
}
.entry:last-child:after {
  height: 10px;
  border-top: none;
  transition: border 0.5s;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;
  margin-top: -9px;
}

.entry:only-child:after {
  width: 20px;
  height: 0px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.entry:only-child:before {
  display: none;
}

.entry span {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: block;
  min-width: 150px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -15px;
  color: #666;
  font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

#tree .entry span:hover,
#tree .entry span:hover + .branch .entry span {
  background: #e6e6e6;
  color: #000;
  border-color: #a6a6a6;
}

#tree .entry span:hover + .branch .entry::after,
#tree .entry span:hover + .branch .entry::before,
#tree .entry span:hover + .branch::before,
#tree .entry span:hover + .branch .branch::before {
  border-color: #a6a6a6;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="tree">
    <div class="entry"><span>Family</span>
        <div class="branch">
            
          <div class="entry"><span>Husband</span>
            
            <div class="branch">
                
              <div class="entry"><span>Father</span>
                <div class="branch">
                  <div class="entry"><span>Grandfather</span>
                    <div class="branch">
                      <div class="entry"><span>Great Grandfather</span></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="entry"><span>Grandmother</span>
                    <div class="branch">
                      <div class="entry"><span>Great Grandfather</span></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="entry"><span>Granduncle</span>
                    <div class="branch">
                      <div class="entry"><span>Great Grandfather</span></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="entry"><span>Granduncle</span>
                    <div class="branch">
                      <div class="entry"><span>Great Grandfather</span></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="entry"><span>Granduncle</span>
                    <div class="branch">
                      <div class="entry"><span>Great Grandfather</span></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="entry"><span>Granduncle</span>
                    <div class="branch">
                      <div class="entry"><span>Great Grandfather</span></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="entry"><span>Granduncle</span>
                    <div class="branch">
                      <div class="entry"><span>Great Grandfather</span></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="entry"><span>Granduncle</span>
                    <div class="branch">
                      <div class="entry"><span>Great Grandfather</span></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="entry"><span>Granduncle</span>
                    <div class="branch">
                      <div class="entry"><span>Great Grandfather</span></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="entry"><span>Granduncle</span>
                    <div class="branch">
                      <div class="entry"><span>Great Grandfather</span></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="entry"><span>Mother</span>
                <div class="branch">
                  <div class="entry"><span class="hide">Grandfather</span>
                    <div class="branch">
                      <div class="entry"><span>Great Grandfather</span></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
          
        </div>
      </div>
</body>
```

[The desired flowchart that i would like to achieve.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inPQX.png)